# Quotation marks within quotation marks

Tags: python

I have a list of words I am searching for in CSV. I want to save all rows that contain *SAID STRING* into a file called *SAID STRING* but I am having issues with the " "

```
data = open("\"list[x]\".csv","w+")
```

x is an index within the list

Comment: Are you looking for something like `f"{list[x]}.csv"`?

Comment: What about `open("list{}.csv".format(x), "w+")`

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name, since it hides the built-in `list` type which can cause lots of strange bugs.

Comment: just changed the name of the variable and it works fine. Cheers.